# Simple click image opens the image in bigger version like lightbox 2

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I'm looking for a simple javascript that when clicked on an image, makes it appear in bigger version in front of the html, on the middle of the page.

When picture is big, then if clicked anywhere on the page, it dissapears.

Hope you can help me :)

Comment: What did you try for this?

Comment: Well till now I only have this: http://jsfiddle.net/mVvwu/6/
Since my old javascript on my laptop disappeared when it shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery-lightbox.com/fr/jquery-popup-simple-lightbox.html?x=44&y=15

Why not lightbox 2, it's easy to use and powerfull